# Error in checkbox select from array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, checkbox

I have an array that comes from the database. In my controller, I have this code:

```
$rootScope.photobloblist=[];
angular.forEach($scope.photos, function(value3, key3) {
              if(key3=="Landscape"){
                $rootScope.photobloblist=[];
                console.log(key3+"----"+value3.length);
                    angular.forEach(value3, function(value2, key2) {
                              for(var i = 0;i<value2.length;i++){
                                if(key2==Categoryname)
                                  $rootScope.photobloblist.push(value2[i]);
                                console.log( $rootScope.photobloblist);
                              }                      
                     });             
              }

            });
```

And in my html file, I have a table and a checkbox that has an ng-model of item.selected

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in photobloblist" >
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="select" value="selected" ng-model="item.selected"></td>
    <td>{{item}}</td>
    <td><img ng-src='{{ item }}' width='150px' height='100px'></td>
</tr>
```

My problem is that I can't check any of the checkbox and it shows an error of "Cannot create property selected on string". How can I possible fix this error. I need to use checkbo for my delete function

Comment: try using value = {{item.selected}}

Comment: @PJ where will I use that?

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="select" value={{item.selected}}  ng-model="item.selected">

Comment: Any feedback m8?

Answer (score 0):

`$rootScope.photobloblist` is an array of strings that you try to bind on your input but an object / array of objects is expected.

#### Try to create a object for each checkbox:

```
if (key2 === "Categoryname") { 
    $rootScope.photobloblist.push({
       value: value2[i],
       name: value2[i]
       selected: false
    });
 }
```

Comment: @bleykFaust could you please create a working fiddle to reproduce your problem? Thanks

Comment: @bleykFaust so we can't help ya

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, use `ng-true-value` instead of `value`

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in photobloblist" >
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="select" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-model="item.selected"></td>
    <td>{{item}}</td>
    <td><img ng-src='{{ item }}' width='150px' height='100px'></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do this by following code:
As error says you cannot add property to string, you can make a object and do the rest :

```
$scope.photos={
    Landscape:{
        Categoryname : ["cat1","cat2"]
    }
};

$rootScope.photobloblist=[];
angular.forEach($scope.photos, function(value3, key3) {
    if(key3=="Landscape"){
        $rootScope.photobloblist=[];
        angular.forEach(value3, function(value2, key2) {
            for(var i = 0;i<value2.length;i++){
                if(key2=="Categoryname"){
                    var temp ={};
                    temp.value=value2[i];
                    $rootScope.photobloblist.push(temp);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```